# Nylon 6,6 synthesis yield

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, stoichiometry

This is the nylon 6,6 reaction

[image]

Having these data available, I would need to know the theoretical quantities, in grams, of the monomers

[image]

My attempt:
Adipoyl chloride is our limiting reactant so theoretical mass is the weighted mass.
Hexamethylenediamine and adipoyl chloride are in 1:1 ratio, so amine theoretical mol are the same of adipoyl chloride: if the calculations are correct, $0.0022\;\text{mol}$.
From which, the theoretical mass of amine will be

$$ 0.0022\;\text{mol} \times 116.21\;\text{g/mol} = 0.2557\;\text{g} $$

Any advice?

Comment: No ! Your calculation gives the mass of the dimer, with $n$ = $2$. But the nylon 6,6 is a polymer with a rather high value of $n$. Its molar mass is probably higher than $100'000$. I don't know whether this value is known.

Comment: I changed the question: what I need to know are the theoretical quantities, in grams, of the monomers. I gave it a try: could you tell me if this is correct?

Comment: Your calculation is correct. $\pu{2.2 mmol}$ of the amine weighs $\pu{0.2557 g}$ and this will react with $\pu{2.2 mmol}$ adipoyl chloride, which weighs $\pu{0.4020 g}$